# How to show full JSON array list data?

Tags: json, flutter, api

I'm creating a global search field in my app with API. For that, I took a TextFormField. Where after clicking the search button it will show nearly match data from API.
I can print the ArrayList data but for that, I have to give an index number `Text("Name: ${widget.rresponse.data[0].name}"),` but I want the whole array list .

**My `searchByUser()` API function** . After statusCode==200 it will navigate me to second page and there it will print my Json response. *[Below I put my JSON response from postman]*

```
  Future<void> searchByUser() async {
var jsonResponse;
if (searchController.text.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://kfkdkfkfkdfkdkfdkfkdkfdfkdfkdfkdkfdkffdk"),
      body: ({
        'SearchKey': searchController.text,
      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context)=>AfterSearchPage(
          rresponse: SearchApiResponse.fromJson(jsonResponse))));// displ
  

   } else {
        print("Wronggooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
        print(response.body);
      }
    } else {}
   }
```

In second page I'm able to print `status` and `message` easily and also able to print array
list data with index[] number But I want whole arrayList at a time.

```
  class AfterSearchPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final SearchApiResponse rresponse;
  const AfterSearchPage({required this.rresponse});
  @override
  _AfterSearchPageState createState() => _AfterSearchPageState();
}

class _AfterSearchPageState extends State<AfterSearchPage> {

  // var responseRef;
  //  _SecondState(this.responseRef);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              


              Text("Status: ${widget.rresponse.status}"),
              Text("Message: ${widget.rresponse.message}"),
              Text("Name: ${widget.rresponse.data[0].name}"),//==??????????????????????????????????????
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),

              OutlinedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => Home2(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.exit_to_app,
                    size: 18,
                  ),
                  label: Text("GoTo Home")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here is my JSON response from postman** how can I achieve all `name` or `Image` at once. I dont want to print one-by-one by giving index number like this: `Text("Name: ${widget.rresponse.data[0].name}"),`

```
    {
    "Status": "1",
    "Message": "3 records found.",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Name": "Angioplasty",
            "EncId": "IujyQXg8KZg8asLvK/FS7g==",
            "Image": "",
            "Extra1": "abdsjh dsgjhgdd gsjjkdkds dddsjkhdj djdjkdh dshjdkhkd dhdhdk sjkghdjkdhkhd dhkdkhdkjhd hkjhkdhd kdjkdjdkjd dhkdkjhdjh ddkdkhd dhdhhd ",
            "Extra2": "",
            "ResultFor": "p6r4bAAI4ybdJySoV+PqGQ=="
        },
        {
            "Name": "Brain surgery",
            "EncId": "B909+U0FIAHIs+sl3IYTvQ==",
            "Image": "",
            "Extra1": "abdsjh dsgjhgdd gsjjkdkds dddsjkhdj djdjkdh dshjdkhkd dhdhdk sjkghdjkdhkhd dhkdkhdkjhd hkjhkdhd kdjkdjdkjd dhkdkjhdjh ddkdkhd dhdhhd . dgjgdjd dgdgjds",
            "Extra2": "",
            "ResultFor": "p6r4bAAI4ybdJySoV+PqGQ=="
        },
        {
            "Name": "Open Heart Surgery",
            "EncId": "7Ch2aVnhokZtRWyJtuDA/A==",
            "Image": "",
            "Extra1": "abdsjh dsgjhgdd gsjjkdkds dddsjkhdj djdjkdh dshjdkhkd dhdhdk sjkghd5kdhkhd dhkdkhdkjhd hkjhkdhd kdjkdjdkjd dhkdkjhdjh ddkdkhd dhdhhd . dgjgdjd dgdgjds",
            "Extra2": "",
            "ResultFor": "p6r4bAAI4ybdJySoV+PqGQ=="
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

[image]

**My Model class**

```
    import 'dart:convert';

SearchApiResponse searchApiResponseFromJson(String str) => SearchApiResponse.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String searchApiResponseToJson(SearchApiResponse data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class SearchApiResponse {
    SearchApiResponse({
        required this.status,
        required this.message,
        required this.data,
    });

    String status;
    String message;
    List<SearchData> data;

    factory SearchApiResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SearchApiResponse(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        data: List<SearchData>.from(json["Data"].map((x) => SearchData.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Status": status,
        "Message": message,
        "Data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class SearchData {
    SearchData({
        required this.name,
        required this.encId,
        required this.image,
        required this.extra1,
        required this.extra2,
        required this.resultFor,
    });

    String name;
    String encId;
    String image;
    String extra1;
    String extra2;
    String resultFor;

    factory SearchData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SearchData(
        name: json["Name"],
        encId: json["EncId"],
        image: json["Image"],
        extra1: json["Extra1"],
        extra2: json["Extra2"],
        resultFor: json["ResultFor"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Name": name,
        "EncId": encId,
        "Image": image,
        "Extra1": extra1,
        "Extra2": extra2,
        "ResultFor": resultFor,
    };
}
```

Comment: The "Result" is the expected result you want to achieve?

Comment: exactly, Im able to print `name` for this specific search, but that does not seem to be correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Column(
          children: getColumnArray(),
        ),
```

```
getColumnArray() {
  List<Widget> widgetList = [];
  
  for (var item in widget.rresponse.data) {
      widgetList.add(Text(widget.rresponse.status));
      widgetList.add(Text(widget.rresponse.message));
      widgetList.add(Text(item.name));
  }

  return widgetList;
}
```

Does this results what you want?

Comment: No actually. Its showing ` type "list <widget>" is not a subtype of type "widget"`  Never mind looping through with column actually work.

Comment: I believe it says that because you tried to use it like this: `children: [ getColumnArray() ],`. What the function returns, is already an array. So you can forget the `[]` brackets.

Comment: You can do this too:  `children: [ ...getColumnArray(), ],` Then you can add more stuff. Like:  `children: [ ...getColumnArray(), Text("This is the end of the column!), ],`

Comment: Ok. what will be the syntax if i want to get access Image.? `NetworkImage` ?

Comment: Depends on from where you get the images. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images

Answer (score 1):

You could loop though your data in your `Column` widget. Something like

```
Column(
    children: [
      for (final item in widget.rresponse.data)
        Column(
          children: [
            Text(item.status),
            Text(item.message),
            Text(item.name),
          ],
        ),
    ]
  )
```

Comment: Not the "data" contains the `status` and `message`

Comment: @stacktrace2234 you are right, I overlooked it.